# Calling Python function in Javascript, reading static files (Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I’m creating a d3 visualisation based on json files chosen by the user like this-

```
d3.json("/data", function(error, graph)
```

This is the app route in views.py

```
    @app.route("/data") #the javascript will call this
def data():
        return(userInput.get_data()) #returns the return value of given function
```

In forms, I have a userInput class, which contains a drop down list. This list consists of names of json files. json_fileCrew is the name of json file chosen by the user.

```
json_fileCrew = SelectField(u"Filename", choices=[(f, f) for f in filenamesCrew])
```

Within this class I have the get_data function:

```
def get_data(json_fileCrew):
        return send_from_directory ("/project/myproject/app/static/Crews" , json_fileCrew)
```

So, when the javascript calls /data it should return the json_fileCrew, but I get this error

```
File "\project\myproject\app\views.py", line
34, in data
    return(userInput.get_data()) #returns the return value of given function
TypeError: get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_fileCrew'
```

This is the full Traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_except
ion
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_e
xception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_requ
est
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "\project\myproject\app\views.py", line
34, in data
    return(userInput.get_data()) #returns the return value of given function
TypeError: get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_fileCrew'
```

Comment: Well, the error traceback is quite obvious: you're calling the function `get_data` without the parameter `json_fileCrew` which is required.

Comment: What's the question? Your `.get_data()` function is defined with an argument, but your code is passing no argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method

```
def get_data(json_fileCrew)
```

but you're not calling it with the required argument

```
return(userInput.get_data())
```

as the error is telling you

```
TypeError: get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_fileCrew'
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent so much time looking at the wrong thing I didn't cop on that the answer was right in front of me!